# how to setup python backend for android app

Tags: android, python, backend

I am very confused right now on where to go to start deploying an android app of mine.

I have written a few hundred lines of code in python as a backend. It basically monitors a website specified for a new uploaded file, downloads it, modifies it a bit, and serves it to client app-users. The app is close to done too, just have to integrate it with the backend.

I could do this at home without a service, but my internet speed at home isn't good enough.

There are so many options like Parse and Google App Engine. I tried watching a few app engine tutorials, but they were so complicated with making APIs and other things. My app is simple and straightforward. How can I implement this?

This will require close to 50GB of space at most for the first phase. I might want to increase according to how my app goes. I am mainly looking for the backend to download the files from the website very fast so I am not behind on schedule.

Or am I going the wrong way with this? I need some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're going about it the right way or not, but you might want to look into using a [vps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server). (I can recommend buyvm.net.) Then you can just install gunicorn or something similar. You might want to look at [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) for hosting files.

Comment: thanks, that gave me a start. But I just don't understand one thing. What is gunicorn and how would it help me? I tried reading about it but not a word penetrated my thick skull. :P Also, would the internet connection speed be good on a vps? Or does it vary depending on which one I buy?

Comment: It's going to vary. But my vps at buyvm.net is pretty quick. Basically the vps is just like having a server. So gunicorn is the server software that receives connections from clients. It can run python code and receive http connections.

Comment: But i dont want clients to interface with my vps, just the amazon s3 account right? So i need to add integration to amazon s3 to my android app and i need to link my vps to amazon s3.

Comment: No... that's not going to work. Basically you client should ask your vps for a file url. Your vps gives your client the url to your S3 file, and then your client downloads the file from S3.

Comment: Oh i see. So how should i connect my vps to s3 in my python code. And how should i connect my android app client to my vps? Sorry for all the questions, im new to this. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Here is a python library for amazon: https://github.com/boto/boto. Here's the S3 API http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/s3/. The rest is up to you. You'll have to write some interface on each side that allows your vps and your android app to communicate.

Comment: Oh no... The vps i want on buyvm is sold out, in both locations. I really liked the price. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: They are always out of stock at night time. Look again tomorrow at noon. Also check this site: http://doesbuyvmhavestock.com/

Comment: i checked at like 4pm, they were out of stock. and according to doesbuyvmhavestock.com , they were out of stock at 1:34PM. Also, do you mind explaining why i should use amazon s3 over just using a cloud service like dropbox to serve my files? its cheaper.

Comment: If it's only for you, no reason. I'd use dropbox. If you have lots of people using it and lots of files you'd probably get better performance out of S3.

Comment: Buyvm still ouof stock today at noon. Any other suggestions, just in case? I couldnt find anything as cheap.

Comment: Either wait for them or check out a site like low end talk to find deals.